# need to create an azure alert that will be fired when error occurs in a runbook

Tags: error-handling, alert, azure-runbook

I need a metric alert that fires when a runbook running 'update statistics' errors. Last night the runbook ran and marked as 'completed' even though I get the following error message:
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "A severe error occurred on the current command.
The results, if any, should be discarded. A severe error occurred on the current command.
The results, if any, should be discarded." At update-statistics-selected-maadf01-tables:65 char:65 + + CategoryInfo :
NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

I wish to use the alerts system flag this error and send an email.    I have been able with my IT teams help to create an alert rule and connect to an action group to flag a job marked as 'failed' and send an email.
That is not what is happening here.  The job is marked as 'completed' with an error condition within the job.
Can I design an alert rule/action group to flag this kind of error within a completed job and send an email when this occurs?
I can provide a screenshot of the alert flagging a 'failed' job if needed.

I hoped that the alert firing an email when the runbook 'failed' would have worked and alerted me.  I created that alert when the runbook actually failed with an internal error.  I think I need another alert with an entirely different condition, or add a condition to the existing alert. But I need info how to capture that error.

Answer (score 0):

> need to create an azure alert that will be fired when error occurs in a runbook

You can use below inbuilt query taken from [Microsoft-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics#list-all-runbooks--jobs-that-completed-successfully-with-errors) to get alerts when you receive an error message :

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION" and Category == "JobStreams" and StreamType_s == "Error" 
| project TimeGenerated , RunbookName_s , StreamType_s , _ResourceId , ResultDescription , JobId_g
```

[image]

Then:

[image]

For the logs to come you need to on logging an tracing in run book as below:

[image]